# What do you call someone who is rigid in his beliefs?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for telling a person is rigid in what he believes, and cannot be swayed into changing his beliefs? Someone who cannot be convinced by reason or facts? A religious person may fall into that category, but I want a generic term that doesn't only consider religious beliefs, but also scientific among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few words that come to mind to describe someone rigid in their beliefs include being dogged, stubborn, uncompromising, dogmatic, hardheaded, obstinate, adamant, adamantine, or narrow-minded. If they are wrong, wrong-headed.

Answer (score 2):

Dogmatic or prejudiced would fit.

Answer (score 1):

Pig-headed may also fit

```
(adj) (derogatory) Obstinate and stubborn to the point of stupidity.
```

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=pigheaded&oldid=51989227

Or obstinate

```
(adj) Stubbornly adhering to an opinion, purpose, or course, usually with implied unreasonableness; persistent.
```

https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=obstinate&oldid=52355849